# How can I remove a VPN service when the remove button is disabled?

Tags: macos, vpn

I added a VPN config. Now I want to remove it, but the **-** button is gray and disabled.

[image]

I checked some answers from [this Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20649071#20649071):

> In Terminal: `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`
>   In Terminal: `networksetup -removenetworkservice networkservice`
>   In Terminal: `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

…but I cannot remove all.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually delete the service by removing it from the relevant preferences file.

Make sure System Preferences and any other software that may attempt to switch network locations is quit before beginning.

1. Make a backup of the preferences file.

   ```
   cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
   sudo cp preferences.plist preferences.plist.old
   ```
2. Give yourself permission to the preference file.

   ```
   sudo chown $USER preferences.plist
   sudo chmod u+w preferences.plist
   ```
3. Open the preference file. I will use Xcode to open the file.

   ```
   open preferences.plist
   ```
4. Use ⌘F to open Find, and search for the name of your VPN service.

   [image]
5. The name of your VPN should be shown in a `UserDefinedName` key.

   [image]
6. Select the ID of the network service above the search result.

   In this case, I would select the one beginning `CD2362`…

   [image]
7. Use <kbd>⌫ backspace</kbd> to delete the entire dictionary. Make sure that the only data that is deleted is this dictionary and its contents, not any of the other dictionaries.
8. Save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 9):

Some VPN interfaces must be removed from the VPN **Profiles** system preference, instead of the Network Interface system preference:

System Preference > **Profiles** > Select VPN profile > Remove.

[image: System Preferences with Profiles highlighted]
[image: Profiles preferences pane]

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this. This actually fixed the problem I have. When the remove button is grayed out, it mean that such VPN service is added by a profile file. And to remove the VPN service, you will need to delete the profile file that's responsible for it.

Comment: This preference pane was removed in macOS Big Sur. You can maybe still access it with `open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Profiles.prefPane`.

Answer (score 2):

networksetup -removenetworkservice networkservice
SHOULD be "networkservice"
The networkservice was the name of the VPN.

For the last one, If you cannot remove the network configuration because you get an error saying it is the only network service on ipv4, click the plus button to add another network configuration, and add one that would be on ipv4 such as 6 to 4, you can then use the terminal command to delete the configuration you were attempting to delete before, and remove the 6 to 4 using the minus button.

See: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/19838/can-t-remove-vpn-network-service-created-by-configuration-profile

Comment: This worked! However, I still have a couple services listed in the Network tab that were installed by HotSpot Shield, but that are no longer listed in `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`. I don't see them in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` either.

Comment: Aha, they exist in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`, which I think can only be edited by disabling SIP. https://help.nextdns.io/t/g9hf600/cant-delete-nextdns-profile-from-macos-network-preferences

Answer (score 1):

In macOS X Sierra after coming across https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3828655?tstart=0 I was able to delete a VPN item that had a greyed out "-" button, even thought I had deleted the "Profile" it was associated with. I did so by the following commands:

1: In terminal, `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` gives a list of the names of the services.

2: In terminal, `networksetup -removenetworkservice "name of service in quotes"` will remove the desired service - the quotes are needed to take care of spaces and other fancy characters - they could be escaped with backslashes (\) instead. This might be the bit that messed up the original author.

3: In terminal `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` gives a list of the names of the services, hopefully showing that the undesired one is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the VPN using command:

```
networksetup -deletepppoeservice "name of your VPN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Monterey the command was `networksetup`, which in Monterey became `networkservices`.

You need `sudo` to delete profiles of another user.

Also bear in mind that profiles installed unter another user are not visible in System Preferences.